# How WordDelimiterFilterFactory to search by token with digits?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I have following configuration:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer",

// Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),

filters = {
    // Normalize token text to lowercase, as the user is unlikely to
    // care about casing when searching for matches
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class),

    @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
        @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "2"),
        @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "5") }) })
```

This works almost as expected but have problems with words which contain digits.

For example:

By `ab` token lucene returns `abcdefg`,  but if I need to find 
 `a1` and there is `a1b1c1d1` it doesn't return anything

How can I change this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have other requirements you didn't mention, you should try removing `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, or at least configuring it properly (setting `preserveOriginal` to `1` in particular) if you really need some of its features.

By default I think `WordDelimiterFilter` turns `"a1b1c1d1"` to something like `["a", "1", "b", "1", "c", "1", "d", "1"]`, which I doubt is useful in an "autocomplete" field.

Comment: @gstackoverflow 1. Have a look at their javadoc, or 2. Have a look at this non-official wiki: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters